# Content of array pointer is altered outside the loop

Tags: arrays, c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, typedef

I'm initializing the values of an array pointer inside a function by allocating it first, and then allocating its content (struct pointers) iterating over the reading of values.

Those are the definition of `Richiesta` and the content of the initializing function:

```c
    typedef struct richiesta {
        int durata;
    } *Richiesta;

    void leggiParametri(Richiesta **richieste, int *n){
        // size
        scanf("%d", n);

        *richieste = calloc(*n, sizeof(struct richiesta));

        //printf("Inside loop:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < *n; i++){
            Richiesta richiesta = malloc(sizeof(struct richiesta));
            printf("%d\t", richiesta);
            scanf("%d", &richiesta->durata);
            (*richieste)[i] = richiesta;
            printf("%d: %d\n", i, (*richieste)[i]->durata);
        }
        printf("Outside loop:\n");
        printf("%d: %d\n", 0, (*richieste)[0]->durata);
        printf("%d: %d\n", 1, (*richieste)[1]->durata);
    }
```

The `main` body:

```c
    Richiesta *richieste = NULL;
    int n = -1;
    leggiParametri(&richieste, &n);
```

Giving the following input:

```
6
4
7
3
8
1
5
15
```

the output is:

```
-858131760  0: 4
-858127616  1: 7
-858127584  2: 3
-858127552  3: 8
-858127520  4: 1
-858127488  5: 5
Outside loop:
0: -858127520
1: 7
```

The problem occurs only for the first element of the array, in the `for` loop it contains the correct value read, while outside it contains that particular value, which corresponds to the address pointed to by the 5th element (printed as an integer).
(the same thing happens even printing the array content inside either an other function or main body)

- What causes the problem?
- Why does it point to that specific value?
- And is there any way to make it work?

Also, uncommenting the line of `printf("Inside loop:\n");` returns a segmentation fault when printing.

Comment: What is this Richiesta richiesta = malloc(sizeof(struct richiesta));?!

Comment: Richiesta is a custom typedef, a pointer to the struct richiesta, so doing that allocate the space required in the heap @VladfromMoscow

Comment: The code does not make a sense. You did not allocate an array of pointers in this statement *richieste = calloc(*n, sizeof(struct richiesta));

Comment: Side note: When using many pointer variables to return multiple values from function, please use temporary variables, and only assign to your pointers at end of function. That way you don't have to deference variables all the time, and it's easier to handle possible error conditions. Now you have `*n` and `(*richieste)` everywhere which makes code harder to read.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please note that code should not be missing vital information, and both definitions of `struct richiesta` and `Richiesta` are like that. Please create [mcve] and remove irrelevant things like variable `t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not allocate an array of pointers in this statement

```
*richieste = calloc(*n, sizeof(struct richiesta));
```

where the type specifier `Richiesta` as you wrote in a comment is an alias for the type `struct richiesta`. You allocated an array of structures.

So this assignment

```
(*richieste)[i] = richiesta;
```

does not make a sense.

It seems you mean

```
*richieste = calloc(*n, sizeof( Richiesta ));
```

Pay attention to that using a typedef for a pointer like this

```
typedef struct richiesta *Richiesta;
```

is a bad idea. This only confuses readers of the code.

Comment: Yes indeed you are right and I have marked the answer, but I have exactly the same code structure with the same "error" but alias defined differently that works correctly, so I did not believe the error was related to your comment

Answer (score 0):

You were caught by a mix of structs and pointer to structs. Allocating an array of pointers to later allocate a struct per element is an anti-pattern and the correct way is indeed to directly allocate an array of structs. But then the code will become:

```
void leggiParametri(Richiesta* richieste, int* n, int* t) {
    // dimensione
    scanf("%d", n);
    //printf("%d\n", *n);
    *richieste = calloc(*n, sizeof(struct richiesta));

    // richieste
    //printf("Inside loop:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        Richiesta richiesta = *richieste + i;
        printf("%p\t", richiesta);
        scanf("%d", &(richiesta->durata));
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, (*richieste)[i].durata);
    }
    printf("Outside loop:\n");
    printf("%d: %d\n", 0, (*richieste)[0].durata);
    printf("%d: %d\n", 1, (*richieste)[1].durata);

    // tempo
    scanf("%d", t);
    //printf("%d\n", *t);
}
```

You could then call the function that way:

```
Richiesta richieste = NULL;
int n, t;
leggiParametri(&richieste, &n, &t);
// other processing....
free(richieste);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not hide pointer behind `typedef`s. It is a vera bad practice.
2. Do not use side effects without special need. You only allocate 1D array and you should use the function return value.

```
typedef struct Richiesta
{
    int durata;
} Richiesta;

Richiesta *leggiParametri(int *n)
{
    Richiesta *richiesta = NULL;
    // size
    if(scanf("%d", n) != 1) { /*error handling */};

    if(n >= 0)
    {
        richiesta = calloc(*n, sizeof(*richiesta));
        //printf("Inside loop:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &richiesta[i].durata);
            printf("%d: %d\n", i, richiesta[i].durata);
        }
        printf("Outside loop:\n");
        printf("%d: %d\n", 0, richiesta[0].durata);
        printf("%d: %d\n", 1, richiesta[1].durata);
    }
    return richiesta;
}
``
```